# Quick Fix j (QFJ) SSL connection to a server fails: certificate_required using jks, csr and crt

Tags: ssl, csr, jks, crt, quickfixj

will appreciate you a help with a SSL problem that I have.
I am using quick fix j version 2.3.1 as initiator.
I am trying to connect to a server that is using SSL

I generated two files using keytool one is .jks and the other is .csr using the commends respectively:

```
keytool -genkey -alias ALIAS -keyalg RSA -keystore JKSNAME.jks -validity 365 -keysize 2048

keytool -certreq -alias ALIAS -keystore JKSNAME.jks -file CSRNAME.csr
```

I then sent the .csr file to the acceptor side and they send back a .crt file, I used this .crt file to generate a new .jks file using commend:

```
keytool -import -alias testalias -file CRTNAME.crt -keypass keypass -keystore JKSNAME2.jks
```

and populate the results in:

```
SocketUseSSL=Y
SocketKeyStore=JKSNAME2.jks 
SocketKeyStorePassword=****
```

but after all this I am unable to connect to the acceptor, getting output:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_required
```

and

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Will appreciate any help with this

Comment: **You must NOT 'generate' a new jks.** For an 'own' cert (one identifying you, not someone/something else), you must import the CA(?)-issued cert to the SAME keystore _and_ entry (alias) where you generated the keypair (and the CSR). In general you must also import any needed chain cert(s), but in this case there probably aren't any. But this is not programming or development.

Comment: thanks @dave_thompson_085,I did as followed: keytool -importcert -file CRTNAME.crt -keystore JKSNAME.jks -alias server_sign_crt and I still see the same exceptions. when I open the jks I see "Your keystore contains 2 entries" with the alias that I used to generate the jks file and the alias I used in inserting the .crt to the jks (ServerSignCrt). I'm not sure It's worth mentioning but the .csr file I generated contain BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST in the header and footer while the acceptor side was expecting BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST to be able to generate the .crt file they removed the NEW

Comment: If the alias you used to generate the file (and more importantly the keypair _in_ the file) is different from the alias you used to import the cert, you didn't follow my instruction, and therefore didn't get the correct result. Please read the words "same keystore _and_ entry (alias)". On your second point, using 'NEW' with 'CERTIFICATE REQUEST' is indeed a sometimes troublesome issue, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-7 , but in your case it has been dealt with and is not _now_ a problem for you.

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085 thanks again for replying, I did as you suggested and use the same alias as i did for the creation of the .jks and .csr from steps 1 and 2 and when I ran eytool -importcert -file CRTNAME.crt -keystore JKSNAME.jks -alias server_sign_crt I got: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply, when i open the .crt file I can see that there is only one header and footer in the file

Comment: Sorry, I forgot keytool requires the full chain (including root); even if you don't need an actual intermediate/chain cert -- which was only my guess, I'm not _certain_ -- you still need the root. Ask the acceptor to give you, or point you to, their root cert and also the the chain cert(s) if any, put it or each of them in a file, and import it, or each from the top (root) downward, to a unique alias in the keystore (not the one for your key, and if multiple not the same as each other); THEN import the server cert to the key  alias as previously stated.

Comment: thanks  for the help @dave_thompson_085, in the end, I used Stunnel it was much easier